# Find frequency of combinations of "Child Types" in a one to many relationship

Tags: mysql

A user can create "tags". A tag can be assigned to multiple parents. What we are trying to do is find out how frequently combinations of tags are used. We also want to know which parents the combinations are linked to.

We consider tags to be used together if they have the sam

```
Parent a, value $200
Child Tag x
Child Tag y
Child Tag z

Parent b, value $300
Child Tag x
Child Tag z

Parent c, $400
Child Tag y
Child Tag z
```

In the above case, the tags y,z are used together 2 times - on parent a and parent c.  Total value of the y,z combination is $600.

Similarly the tags x,z are used together on parent a and parent b. Total value of the x,z combination is $500.

The sort of searches we want to do are:

```
"find combinations of any 2 tags that share a parent"
"find the total value for each combination of 2 tags that share a parent"
```

I'm stumped as to how to do this in a query and I keep coming back to using temp tables.

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship, not one-to-many, but I think based on the rest of your question you know that.

Comment: Not really. A similar scenario would be invoices with multiple lines. Each item has a product code. The question "which products are typically purchased together" is the same type of query. It 1 invoice:many lines and 1 line:1 product

Comment: There are many parents for each tag, and many tags for each parent. If you model it like a many-to-many, rephrasing the first question, "how many parents does each pair of tags share?" makes me think an outer join on the relationship table can do it. `select p1.parent_id, p1.tag_id, p2.tag_id from parent_has_tag as p1 left join parent_has_tag as p2 using(parent_id)` gets you a list of every tag combination for each parent. From there you can answer the above questions.

Comment: Or in the vocabulary of your comment, 1 invoice has many products, and each product appears on many invoices.

Comment: If you have a table for line items, you're halfway home, since that will have an invoice id and the product id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's important to recognize that this is a many-to-many problem, not a one-to-many. Each parent has many tags, and each tag is applied to many parents.

If you modify your model to reflect this, you will have a table something like this:

```
parent_id | tag_id
------------------
a         | x
a         | y
a         | z
b         | x
b         | z
c         | y
c         | z
```

and so forth.

Now you can join the table on itself to get a list of tag combinations for each parent:

```
select p1.parent_id, p1.tag_id, p2.tag_id from parent_has_tag as p1 left join parent_has_tag as p2 using(parent_id) where p2.tag_id > p1.tag_id;
```

`>` is used to eliminate reporting 'x,x' as a pair, and also returning both 'x,y' and 'y,x'.

That isn't really what you are looking for, but that is the cornerstone that will allow you to answer your above questions. For instance, "how many times does each tag combination appear?" is answered something like this:

```
SELECT count(1) AS `frequency`, GROUP_CONCAT(p1.parent_id) AS `parents`, CONCAT_WS(',', p1.tag_id, p2.tag_id) AS `pair` 
    FROM parent_has_tag AS p1 LEFT JOIN parent_has_tag AS p2 USING(parent_id) where p2.tag_id > p1.tag_id
    GROUP BY `pair`;
```

This gives you how many times each tag combination appears, and a for-now gratuitous list of the parents that have those combinations. But the answer to your next question is just to add up the values of the parents:

```
SELECT count(1) AS `frequency`,
    SUM(`parents`.`value`) AS `total_value`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p1.parent_id) AS `parents`,
    p1.tag_id AS `tag1`,
    p2.tag_id AS `tag2` 
FROM parent_has_tag AS p1 
JOIN parent_has_tag AS p2 ON p1.parent_id = p2.parent_id AND p2.tag_id > p1.tag_id
JOIN parents on p1.parent_id = parents.id
GROUP BY p1.tag_id, p2.tag_id
```

I think there is room for optimization (this version is smarter about grouping than the one above, for instance), but that is the core of a way to get the data you want.

With the above starting data, the result of that query looks like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+------+------+
| frequency | total_value | parents | tag1 | tag2 |
+-----------+-------------+---------+------+------+
|         2 |         600 | c,a     |    x |    y |
|         2 |         500 | b,a     |    x |    z |
|         1 |         200 | a       |    y |    z |
+-----------+-------------+---------+------+------+
```

Comment: In the vocabulary or your comment above, each row in the `parent_has_tag` table represents a line item in the invoice.

Comment: You're welcome! If it works for you, feel free to mark it as correct.

Comment: Done - thanks Jerry - I was scratching my head at that issue!